# Create a table with current date appended to table name in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, procedure

I know that this is a terrible practice but this is what I am being asked for. This procedure will be executed about once a month but that could change. I need the format of the new table name to be `staff.20150818` which is `staff.yyyymmdd`. When I run my procedure, the table name is `@currentDate` instead of what I need it to be. In SQL Azure, I cannot use `PREPARE` which has been a factor in many of the solutions I have found. Here is the code I have been working on:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @currentDate varchar(500);
SET @currentDate = 'staff.' +(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),3));

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[@currentDate] (
 [staffID] int identity(1,1) primary key,
 [firstName] nvarchar(35),
 [lastName] nvarchar(35),
 [positionTitle] nvarchar(45),
 [leaID] nvarchar(15),
 [schoolID] nvarchar(15),
 [phoneNumber] nvarchar(24),
 [email] nvarchar(128),
 [username] nvarchar(20),
 [password] nvarchar(max),
 [code1] nvarchar(5),
 [code2] nvarchar(5),
 [date_created] datetime2(7),
 [date_updated] datetime2(7)
) INSERT INTO [@currentDate](firstName, lastName, positionTitle, leaID, schoolID, phoneNumber, email, username, password, code1, code2)
  SELECT firstName, lastName, positionTitle, leaID, schoolID, phoneNumber, email, username, password, code1, code2
  FROM Staff

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use dynamic SQL, Concat your SQL statement into a string, including converting the date time to varchar, then call EXEC or sp_executeSql on it.

You can't pass the table name as a variable to sp_executeSql; you need to have already resolved that in the @sql string.

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me come to the conclusion of concatenating. I didn't use the method, but I used something very similar.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using dynamic sql?
Something like this should work :

```
 EXECUTE sp_executesql 
 N'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[@currentDate] (
 [staffID] int identity(1,1) primary key,
 ...',
 N'@currentDate varchar(500)',
 @currentDate = 'staff.' +(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),3))
```

Documentation on [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)